# Airflow encrypted variables

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

After updating `Airflow` to `1.9` all variables are created as encrypted.

Is it possible to disable encryption ?

Comment: Any advances with disabling encryption?

Answer (score 1):

1-The Croods way....

```
 from airflow.models import get_fernet
    from airflow.models import Variable
    var_to_decryp = Variable.get("var_name",deserialize_json=True)
    fernet = get_fernet()
    decryp_value = fernet.decrypt(bytes(var_to_decryp, 'utf-8')).decode()
```

2-The right way will be using  get_val() from Variable model:

```
def get_val(self):
    log = LoggingMixin().log
    if self._val and self.is_encrypted:
        try:
            fernet = get_fernet()
            return fernet.decrypt(bytes(self._val, 'utf-8')).decode()
        except InvalidFernetToken:
            log.error("Can't decrypt _val for key={}, invalid token "
                      "or value".format(self.key))
            return None
        except Exception:
            log.error("Can't decrypt _val for key={}, FERNET_KEY "
                      "configuration missing".format(self.key))
            return None
    else:
        return self._val
```

but i don't know how ,that is home work.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Variable class within the DAG from which you need to set the unencrypted variable:

```
import json
from typing import Any, Optional
import airflow.models as models
from airflow.utils.session import provide_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

class Variable(models.Variable):
    def set_val_unencrypted(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            self._val = value
            self.is_encrypted = False

    @classmethod
    @provide_session
    def set_unencrypted(
        cls,
        key: str,
        value: Any,
        description: Optional[str] = None,
        serialize_json: bool = False,
        session: Session = None,
    ):
        # check if the secret exists in the custom secrets backend.
        cls.check_for_write_conflict(key)
        if serialize_json:
            stored_value = json.dumps(value, indent=2)
        else:
            stored_value = str(value)

        Variable.delete(key, session=session)
        var = Variable(key=key, description=description)
        var.set_val_unencrypted(stored_value)
        session.add(var)
        session.flush()
```

Then when you need to set the unencrypted variable you just call `Variable.set_unencrypted(<key>, <value>, ...)` (instead of `Variable.set()`)