# Airflow Password Variable

Tags: variables, encryption, airflow

I have airflow variable named as mysql_password and set its value which is visible as **** after saving. When I try to access it using Variable.get, it still returns the **** value instead of the actual password. I read that if the variable name contains keyword 'password', it will be encrypted. But it does not seem to work this way. Any method of how to reading the value of this encrypted variable?

Comment: do you have fernet key? AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY

Comment: no, how do i set that? I read about Fernet but have not used it yet.

Comment: Check in airflow.cfg if AIRFLOW_CORE_FERNET_KEY is empty

Comment: Still how to get the correct value? As doing Variable.get returns **** and hence unable to connect to mysql as password is not valid.

Comment: Did you see answers here that might help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074060/airflow-encrypted-variables

Comment: not really helpful.